# How to remove text from each select option using jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace

I have a list of options that looks like this:

```
<select id="input_13">
        <option class="level-1" value="35">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Eielson AFB</option> 
    <option class="level-1" value="36">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Elmendorf AFB</option> 
    <option class="level-1" value="37">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fort Greely</option> 
</select>
```

How can I use .replace to move through each option and take out all the spaces?

So far I've tried this, which is not working:

```
jQuery("#input_13).each(function () {
            (this).text().replace('&nbsp','1234');
});
```

Comment: If that's really you're code, you're missing some quotes: jQuery("#input_13)

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing out the quotation marks. I fixed those, but that wasn't the main problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
 $("#input_13").find("option").each(function (index, option) {
        $(option).html($(option).html().replace(/&nbsp;/g,''));
 });
```

jsFiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/rwWv7/5/

Comment: This will only replace the first occurrence of `&nbsp`, and it will leave the `;`...

Comment: Thanks this did the trick! I just had to write out replace('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;','') to get them all.

Comment: According to @Felix, I updated the code again, with this new one you don't need to repeat it three times.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery("#input_13")
```

The mistake here is that you are selecting the select element so each will only loop through select.

```
$(this).text().replace('&nbsp','1234');
```

The mistake here is that you are replacing &nbsp with 1234 but are not assigning it back to the element. Also it would only replace the first &nbsp. html is a better option here as text would convert &nbsp to space.

The correct code would be:

```
$("#input_13 option").each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/g,''));
});
```

Looks like the server-side code is generating the &nbsp's. If possible it would be better to modify the server-side code to not generate them rather that using JavaScript to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
jQuery("#input_13 option").each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\u00a0/g,''));
});
```

Note that it's using the unicode equivalent of `&nbsp;` to replace.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjorn/2Rfmw/14/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `html()` so that the `&nbsp;` are taking literally. You can also pass a function to `html()` which makes things very easy:

```
$('#input_13 option').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace('/&nbsp;/g','');
});
```

Two things to note: `replace` *returns* the new string and you need a regular expression, because be default, `replace` only replaces the first occurrences of the search string.

Comment: This looks very clean. I tried it but it didn't work though. Not sure why?